# Снижение скорости работы программы

Tags: c#, парсер

Имеется парсер, написанный на c#. Заметил, что при запуске скорость работы выше, чем, к примеру, через несколько часов. Если его перезапустить, то скорость работы будет выше. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: В чём угодно. Например, в том, что вы не завершаете вспомогательные подпроцессы корректно, и они едят процессорное время. Или в том, что ваш компьютер переходит в режим пониженного энергопотребления. Или в том, что ваши данные в начале более лёгкие, а чем дальше тем более сложные для разбора. Без кода можно только гадать на кофейной гуще. Предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под вспомогательными подпроцессами?

Comment: Это вы как автор программы должны сказать, я не знаю, я исходников не видел.